# how to extract pdf from object stream using python?

Tags: python, pdf

```
%PDF-1.4 %Çåôåð 3 0 obj
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode /Length 2305
>>
stream
’›x<Lƒ&Ó o›éäü51⁄4¶†wiËÊþHã›3⁄4é{øöKœ¦ñuÖ„—W1⁄4å? 
üÖé„£1ŽøÃ$·LÂÿKê„×A”áýã.<O ̄Þƒ1⁄41⁄2PT@?‰ùTMß:í ̈¥μàŸ*áíŽ·hî†Ñôo  ́ . 
lÁ&Aj+k- ¿uú'Uù•Gá8A4ŠÏÃèòü£¦Î›Ã(
*°ei”,1ÇO\\®é)91⁄2FAÄ ̄ ̧æc ̧ø§í÷°E(å—@þ¿1ø AF×Ù•Ã0“4 †×
×ì!Ìß“ qÑ@ÙÇÙ‹?où#¿¶T0{a...`CÅE§÷Zùμ_{ ̈ (ûƒ 
endstream
endobj
```

I want to extract meaningful pdf from this stream which is encoded using FlateDecode. 
I have tried using zlib library but still not getting the output required. Also there are xref tables and images subtype which are also encoded. if anybody knows how to convert these pdf objects into pdf using python then please help

Comment: [Maybe try this?]( https://gist.github.com/averagesecurityguy/ba8d9ed3c59c1deffbd1390dafa5a3c2) Please add what you have tried till now to the question.

Comment: I have tried this code https://gist.github.com/averagesecurityguy/ba8d9ed3c59c1deffbd1390dafa5a3c2.  But this further decodes in the format of BT ET TJ etc. How to extract pdf from this.

Comment: The result I got by using this code is:  q Q q 0 0 595.28 841.89 re W n /Cs1 cs 1 1 1 sc 0 -0.8798828 596 843 re f
Q q 53.94292 54.4471 487.3942 733.5 re W n /Cs1 cs 0 0 0 sc q 1 0 0 1 57 775
cm BT 11 0 0 11 0 0 Tm /TT1 1 Tf [ ( ) 0.2 ( ) 0.2 ( ) 0.2 ( ) 0.2 ( ) 0.2